# positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. | Futter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[There is error saying : 'error: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. (not_enough_positional_arguments at [designers] lib\providers\user_provider.dart:8),'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsQSH.png)

[I can fix Above error if delete this code (rounded by redline, But, if i delete it there shows another error, 3rd picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fubM.png)

[There what happened when i delete code which shows in 2nd picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Shy.png)

Then, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error speaks for itself: the `AuthMethods` class takes 1 argument in its constructor:

```
AuthMethods(FirebaseAuth instance);
```

To use the `AuthMethods` class, you need to provide a `FirebaseAuth` object.

However, from what I can see in your code, this parameter is not used. The `FirebaseAuth` instance is directly retrieved at line 12 with `FirebaseAuth.instance`.

To solve your issues, remove `AuthMethods` constructor:

```
class AuthMethods {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 
  Future<model.User> getUserDetails() async {
    // Your implementation here
  }
}
```

In your `loginUser()` method, simply call `AuthMethods` as:

```
void loginUser() async {
  AuthMethods().loginUser(
    email: emailController.text,
    password: passwordController.text,
    context: context,
  );
}
```